# PHP and C# HMAC SHA256

Tags: c#, php, sha256, hmac

I need to convert the following php code in C#:

```
$res = mac256($ent, $key);
$result = encodeBase64($res);
```

where

```
function encodeBase64($data)
{
    $data = base64_encode($data);
    return $data;
}
```

and

```
function mac256($ent,$key)
{
    $res = hash_hmac('sha256', $ent, $key, true);//(PHP 5 >= 5.1.2)
    return $res;
}
```

I use the following C# code:

```
byte[] res = HashHMAC(ent, key);
string result = System.Convert.ToBase64String(res);
```

where

```
public byte[] HashHMAC(string ent, byte[] key)
{
   byte[] toEncryptArray =System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591).GetBytes(ent);

   HMACSHA256 hash = new HMACSHA256(key);
   return hash.ComputeHash(toEncryptArray);
}
```

The complete php source code available at this [link](http://www.redsys.es/wps/wcm/connect/redsys/45b1e5d9-689f-4df0-b2e5-7bff1984755c/API_PHP.zip?MOD=AJPERES)

I also check this post [hmac_sha256 in php and c# differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699041/hmac-sha256-in-php-and-c-sharp-differ)

and this one [C# equivalent to hash_hmac in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12804231/c-sharp-equivalent-to-hash-hmac-in-php)

But the results are not the same.

Comment: Can this help you?: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html#signature-v4-examples-dotnet

Comment: @Ivar I used the function reported in the link, but the result is the same of the mine (HashHMAC).

Comment: In my example, according to further investigations the Key length is 8 bytes. [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9c9tf8wc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reports that in case of key long less then 64, it should be automatically padded.
Is there a difference between PHP and C# in padding operation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

```
static byte[] hmacSHA256(String data, String key)
{
    using (HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key)))
    {
        return hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data));
    }
}
```

If I call this code:

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(hmacSHA256("1234", "1234")).Replace("-", "").ToLower());
```

It returns:

```
4e4feaea959d426155a480dc07ef92f4754ee93edbe56d993d74f131497e66fb
```

When I run this in PHP:

```
echo hash_hmac('sha256', "1234", "1234", false);
```

It returns

```
4e4feaea959d426155a480dc07ef92f4754ee93edbe56d993d74f131497e66fb
```

Comment: your answered is correct, but be aware of parameter bool raw_output in hash_hmac ->  hash_hmac('sha256', "1234", "1234", true);

if raw_output set true, we do not have to BitConverter.ToString, replace "-" to "" and ToLower(). 

Then the code in c# become just : hmacSHA256("1234", "1234")

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure that you're dealing with the new RedSys SHA256 signature implementation. Also I saw that you have some issue with the 3DES encryption between PHP and C#.

First at all you must get the base 64 string with all the payment parameters. You can achieve it with this code:

```
public static string GetParameters(string merchantCode, string terminal, int currency, string transactionType, decimal amount, string merchantOrder, string merchantIdentifier, string merchantPost, string urlOk, string urlKo)
        {
            var jsonValues = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "Ds_Merchant_Amount", amount.ToString().Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, "") },
                { "Ds_Merchant_Order", merchantOrder},
                { "Ds_Merchant_MerchantCode", merchantCode },
                { "Ds_Merchant_Currency", currency.ToString() },
                { "Ds_Merchant_TransactionType", transactionType },
                { "Ds_Merchant_Terminal", terminal },
                { "Ds_Merchant_Identifier", merchantIdentifier },
                { "Ds_Merchant_MerchantURL", merchantPost },
                { "Ds_Merchant_UrlOK", urlOk},
                { "Ds_Merchant_UrlKO",  urlKo}
            }.Select(kvp => "\"{0}\":\"{1}\"".Formato(kvp.Key.ToUpper(), kvp.Value));

            var jsonString = "{" + string.Join(",", jsonValues) + "}";

            return Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(jsonString));
        }
```

Once you have the JSON string in base 64, you must apply 3DES to merchant order parameter with the key provided by RedSys:

```
public static string GetTransactionEncryptionKey(string merchantOrder, string encryptKey)
        {
            using (var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
            {
                tdes.IV = new byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
                tdes.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptKey);
                tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
                tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

                var toEncrypt = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(merchantOrder);
                var result = tdes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);

                return Convert.ToBase64String(result);
            }
        }
```

As you can see, the encryption key provided by RedSys is base 64 string so you don't need to calculate the MD5 hash for the 3DES algorithm.

Then we go for the SHA256 signature:

```
public static string GetSignature(string base64Parameters, string base64tranEncryptKey)
        {
            using (var sha = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(base64tranEncryptKey)))
            {
                var hash = sha.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(base64Parameters));

                return Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
            }
        }
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I solved "traslanting" the php class provided by redsys into C# and it works. I used the suggestions provided at the following links
[Conversion of strtr php function in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33474491/conversion-of-strtr-php-function-in-c-sharp) [PHP and C# 3DES Encryption] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33373764/php-and-c-sharp-3des-encryption?noredirect=1#comment54563282_33373764)

Answer (score 0):

Redsys provides libraries for php and java.

Starting from the java library, I've translated the ApiMacSha256 class to C#

```
public class ApiMacSha256 {
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////                    FUNCIONES AUXILIARES:                              ///////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    /** 3DES Function */
    private byte[] encrypt_3DES(byte[] key, string data) {
        //http://www.mywebexperiences.com/2012/12/11/crypting-data-using-3des-c/
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/33479952/2938518
        using (var tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()) {
            tdes.IV = new byte[8] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            tdes.Key = key;
            tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

            var toEncrypt = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            var result = tdes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(toEncrypt, 0, toEncrypt.Length);

            return result;
        }
    }

    /** MAC Function */
    private byte[] mac256(string dsMerchantParameters, byte[] secretKo) {
        //http://stackoverflow.com/a/17315619/2938518
        byte[] hash;
        using (var hmac = new HMACSHA256(secretKo)) {
            hash = hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dsMerchantParameters));
        }

        return hash;
    }

    /** Base64 Functions */
    private string encodeB64String(byte[] data) {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(data, Base64FormattingOptions.None);
    }

    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////////        FUNCIONES PARA LA GENERACIÓN DEL FORMULARIO DE PAGO:          ////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public String createMerchantSignature(string merchantParamsB64, string claveComercio, string OrderId) {
        byte[] clave = Convert.FromBase64String(claveComercio);
        byte[] secretKo = encrypt_3DES(clave, OrderId);

        // Se hace el MAC con la clave de la operación "Ko" y se codifica en BASE64
        byte[] hash = mac256(merchantParamsB64, secretKo);
        String res = encodeB64String(hash);
        return res;
    }
}
```

The main method 'createMerchantSignature', requires a string encoded in base64 of the merchant params embeded in a json structure, the secret key of the merchant and the OrderId.