# Conversion of strtr php function in C#

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, replace, strtr

Need to convert this php code in C#

```
strtr($input, '+/', '-_')
```

Does an equivalent C# function exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `PHP` method `strtr()` is translate method and not `string replace` method.
If you want to do the same in `C#` then use following:

As per your comments

```
string input = "baab";
var output = input.Replace("a", "0").Replace("b","1");
```

> Note : There is no exactly similar method like `strtr()` in `C#`.

[You can find more about String.Replace method here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please note the example reported in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)
   `echo strtr("baab", "ab", "01");`
returns
    `1001`
Using your code the result is
   `ba01`.

Comment: `echo strtr("hi all, I said hello","ah","ha");` has a different result in php.

Answer (score 4):

@Damith @Rahul Nikate @Willem van Rumpt

Your solutions generally work. There are particular cases with different result:

```
echo strtr("hi all, I said hello","ah","ha");
```

returns

```
ai hll, I shid aello
```

while your code:

```
ai all, I said aello
```

I think that the php `strtr` replaces the chars in the input array at the same time, while your solutions perform a replacement then the result is used to perform another one.
So i made the following modifications:

```
   private string MyStrTr(string source, string frm, string to)
    {
        char[] input = source.ToCharArray();
        bool[] replaced = new bool[input.Length];

       for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
            replaced[j] = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < frm.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j<input.Length;j++)
                if (replaced[j] == false && input[j]==frm[i])
                {
                    input[j] = to[i];
                    replaced[j] = true;
                }
        }
        return new string(input);
    }
```

So the code

```
MyStrTr("hi all, I said hello", "ah", "ha");
```

reports the same result as php:

```
ai hll, I shid aello
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   string input ="baab";
   string strfrom="ab";
   string strTo="01";
   for(int i=0; i< strfrom.Length;i++)
   {
     input = input.Replace(strfrom[i], strTo[i]);
   }
   //you get 1001
```

sample method:

```
string StringTranslate(string input, string frm, string to)
{
      for(int i=0; i< frm.Length;i++)
       {
         input = input.Replace(frm[i], to[i]);
       }
      return input;
}
```

Comment: Please note the example reported in [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)
   `echo strtr("baab", "ab", "01");`
return
    `1001`
Using your code the result is
   `ba01`.

Comment: string input ="baab";
    string f="ab";
    string t="01";
    for(int i=0; i< f.Length;i++)
    {
      input = input.Replace(f[i], t[i]);
    }

Comment: `echo strtr("hi all, I said hello","ah","ha");` has a different result in php.

Answer (score 1):

The <s>horrors</s> wonders of PHP...I got confused by your comments, so looked it up in the manual. Your form replaces individual characters (all "b"'s get to be "1", all "a"'s get to be "0"). There's no direct equivalent in C#, but simply replacing twice will get the job done:

```
string result = input.Replace('+', '-').Replace('/', '_')
```

Comment: `echo strtr("hi all, I said hello","ah","ha");` has a different result in php.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case there are still developers that come from PHP and are missing the strtr php function.

There is now a String extension for this:
https://github.com/redflitzi/StrTr 
It has the two-strings option for character replacement as well as Array/List/Dictionary support for replacing words.

Character replacement looks like this:

```
var output = input.StrTr("+/", "-_");
```

Words replacement:

```
var output = input.StrTr(("hello","hi"), ("hi","hello"));
```